# How To Insert a DECIMAL(a,b) Value Into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point

I have a table with a DECIMAL(10,6) column. I have a string representation of a float (e.g. 35.3123122). I am using php to insert the value. I used floatval($string) to insert and it did not work. I also tried to insert the string itself with no success. Do I need to format the float value exactly to match the 10,6 criteria. If so, How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: "it did not work" - great explanation. How about you post the string after you `floatval` it and the exact error message you get (if any) when inserting fails?

Comment: It is not the same issue. The database is refusing to insert the row. I also have my string with the "." not the ","

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for the positive feedback :) . after I use floatval it returns the same number but it becomes of FLOAT type. I am not able to see the error message but I know it fails to insert, and I am sure the error is from the DECIMAL column.

Comment: And todays's issue of "Guess my code" is brought to you by the letter "P" and the number "35.3123122"

Comment: @MarkBaker Instead of your failed sacrasm. Maybe you can be of actual use by providing the concept of how MYSQL's data type works. I also doubt that a couple of basic insert and conversion lines will show the problem

Comment: @Pacemaker - would you like to place a bet on your statement? Since you won't show the code, nor try to get the error (MySQL always gives you the error if something goes wrong), then we can only play the game Mark mentioned.

Comment: echo your insert query and check for the mysql error

Comment: PHP only has one float type, you can't "format" that without changing it from a float, other than rounding (which I assume isn't what you want to do).... showing us the code, and the actual MySQL error may actually help us to help you... without that, al we can do is guess or be sarcastic

Comment: I am trying to find a way to echo debug but cannot find it ( I am using Codeigniter's activerecord). @N.B. I am trying to get a conceptual answer, it is not always about the code.

Comment: If I specify DECIMAL(10,6). Can I insert a number like: 12.112233 or I have to format it like this first before inserting: 0012.112233 ?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything out of the ordinary or special. You don't even need to convert the string to PHP internal float type. It just has to be a string such as `10.123456`. You don't have to zero fill it, it just has to contain the dot for decimal separator. The input you posted is too long, and in the case of too long of a number, you will get MySQL warning and it's going to truncate the number and still insert it. Your problem is in the code, hence the questions are about the code.

Comment: Thanks N.B. I will see what I can do from here.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but the value of "35.3123122" has 7 digits after the decimal point. DECIMAL(10,6) is 10 digits in total with a maximum of 6 digits past the decimal point.

Comment: I tried increasing to DECIMAL(11,7). but still not working.